# linux test module build fails with 'no input file' from gcc

Tags: linux, makefile, linux-device-driver

I'm trying to build a test module for linux according to a book.
I have done this simple example in the past, but it fails this morning.
in my directory ~/LINUX, I have a file like this.

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
MODULE_LICENSE("Dual BSD/GPL");

static int hello_init(void)
{
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Hello, world\n");
    return 0;
}

static void hello_exit(void)
{
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Goodbye, cruel world\n");
}

module_init(hello_init);
module_exit(hello_exit);
```

'uname -r' shows '4.15.0-99-generic'. the Makefile is like this (in ~/LINUX)

```
obj-m += test1.ko

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/4.15.0-99-generic/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/4.15.0-99-generic/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

when I run make, it gives me

```
make -C /lib/modules/4.15.0-99-generic/build M=/home/ckim/LINUX modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-99-generic'
scripts/Makefile.build:336: target '/home/ckim/LINUX/test1.ko' doesn't match the target pattern
  CC [M]  /home/ckim/LINUX/test1.ko
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
scripts/Makefile.build:337: recipe for target '/home/ckim/LINUX/test1.ko' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/ckim/LINUX/test1.ko] Error 1
Makefile:1577: recipe for target '_module_/home/ckim/LINUX' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/ckim/LINUX] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-99-generic'
Makefile:4: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Isn't `obj-m += test1.ko` supposed to be `obj-m += test1.o`?

Comment: @kaylum  Ah! That was it! Thanks. if you want, make it an answer, than I'll select it.

Comment: Please note: you should never use `make` when you invoke a recursive make.  You should always use the variable `$(MAKE)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
obj-m += test1.ko
```

should be

```
obj-m += test1.o
```